# How the each set $[-1,0)$ , $(0,1]$ are open in Y?

Tags: general-topology

Let Y denotes the subspace $[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$ of real line $\mathbb{R}$.
How the each set $[-1,0)$ ,  $(0,1]$ are open in Y .
The definition of Open Set is that it must not contain its boundaries.
the author (Munkres) says that the Sets $[-1,0)$ ,  $(0,1]$  are open in Y but not in $\mathbb{R}$.The question may sound easy but please try to explain. thanks !.
what i think is that if i take a point $-1$ and  make a open ball of radius $\epsilon$ then it will cross the boundary $-1$ hence the set can't be open.

Comment: The open ball of radius $\epsilon < 1$ in $Y$ centered at $-1$ is just $$\{x \in Y : |x - y| < \epsilon\} = [-1, \epsilon)$$---as far as the space $Y$ is concerned, *there are no points outside $Y$*.

Comment: [-1,0) is closed on $\mathbb{R}$ ,but how to say for [-1,0) in Y

Comment: What author? And note that $[-1,0)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, but is closed in $Y$, and not open in $\mathbb{R}$ but it is open in $Y$. What is the full definition your text uses?

Comment: i am using munkres it says "Let Y denotes the subspace [−1,0)∪(0,1] of real line R.Each of the sets [−1,0),(0,1]are open in Y (although not in R). "

Comment: @HennoBrandsma how (-1,0] is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ it does not contain its limit point.

Comment: I said that $[-1,0)$ is not closed in the reals but closed in $Y$

Comment: can i use relatively open sets to prove that [-1,0) is open in Y  $ \bold{Def.}$ .if $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ then $B \subset A$ is relatively open in $A$ or open in $A$ ,if $B=A\cap G$ where G is open in R

Comment: @Cielo, of course you can use relatively open sets, if you know them. I wasn't sure if you did so my argument just uses the restricted metric.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that given a topological space $X$ and a subset $A \subset X$ the subspace topology on $A$ is defined by declaring the open sets to be sets of the form $U \cap A$, where $U$ is an open subset of $X$.

Given $Y = [-1, 0) \cup (0, 1] \subset \Bbb R$, note that $(0, 2) \cap Y = (0, 1]$. As $(0, 2) \subset \Bbb R$ is open, $(0, 1]$ is open in $Y$. Similarly, $(-2, 0) \cap Y =  [-1, 0)$, thus $[-1, 0)$ is open in $Y$.

But it is clear why neither $[-1, 0)$ nor $(0, 1]$ is open in $\Bbb R$ - both have boundary points.

Comment: Boundary points themselves are not a problem, boundary points that are part of the set are. $(0,1)$ has two boundary points as well, but they're not in the set.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma By "having boundary points", I meant the boundary points are included in the set.

Answer (score 0):

$[-1,0)$ is just an open ball in $Y$ in the subspace metric.

$B_Y(-1,1) = \{y \in Y: d(y, -1) < 1 \}$, where $d$ denotes the metric on $\mathbb{R}$, which is a also (when restricted) the metric on $Y$. Note the $y \in Y$; as far as $Y$ is concerned, there are no points outside $Y$. So no points to the left of $-1$ need be considered, as they're not in $Y$. And then the only points in $Y$ (!) within distance $1$ of $-1$ are exactly those in $[-1,0)$.

So $[-1,0)$ is just an open ball in the metric space $(Y,d)$, and in any metric space, open balls are open sets of the space.

Similarly, $(0,1] = B_Y(1,1)$ as well.